# Negative Binomial: Estimating r (# failures until stopping) when p (success probability) is known

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, negative-binomial-distribution

I have a NB(r,p) distribution (let's say with the conventions of the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)). Suppose I know the success probability p, observe Y the number of successes, but don't know and want to estimate r, the number of failures until the experiment is stopped. Getting a point estimate isn't too hard. One could use MLE or method of moments. But what if I want an interval estimate, like a confidence interval or something similar? One way I can think of is use a Metropolis-Hastings MCMC algorithm in a Bayesian estimation scheme. But I imagine there also must be something simpler. If anyone has a good reference for this, I'd much appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A rule of thumb I have seen when trying not to use a Bayesian prior, is to have an interval containing those values whose likelihood is $\frac18$ or more of the maximum likelihood.  For a normally distributed likelihood with known variance this would correspond to $\pm \log(\frac18) \approx \mp 2.08$ standard deviations, though will differ for other distributions.

Comment: Why not simply directly bootstrap this?

Comment: Bootstrapping is a good idea, nice and simple. @Henry do you have a reference for this rule of thumb? I admit I'm not familiar with that idea.